# How to sort API values in PHP

Tags: php, api, sorting

I am working on a crytomining page that shows all the miners that are active. Right now, it's displaying from an API in PHP:

```
<table class="left">
        <tr><th colspan="3">Connected Miners (POOL)</th></tr>
        <tr><td class="header">Miners Address</td><td class="header">Shares</td><td class="header">Miners Hashrate</td></tr>
        <?php
        $poolminers = json_decode(file_get_contents("<<API LINK>>"), false);
        foreach ($poolminers->body->primary->shared as $miners) {
            echo '<tr><td><a href=<<LINK>>?wallet=' . $miners->worker . '>' . $miners->worker . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' . round($miners->shares, 2) . '</td><td>';
            if ($miners->hashrate / 1000000 < 1000) {
                echo round($miners->hashrate / 1000000, 3) . ' MH/s</td></tr>';
            }
            if ($miners->hashrate / 1000000 > 1000) {
                echo round($miners->hashrate / 1000000000, 3) . ' GH/s</td></tr>';
            }
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

I want to sort by the miner's hashspeed, but I'm unsure how to sort by the "next" value. I tried putting $poolminers into an array, but I received a fatal error for -

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

> Side note - the owner of the site does not want the site info given out, so I add <<>> where the actual links are - sorry for any confusion.

---

So after reading the first answer, I'm wondering if maybe my issue is not so much the sorting (although that is the primary concern) but more of how do I convert an API's data into a multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `usort` function to make this happen: [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

This code should sort your data by hashrate in ascending order:

```php
$json = '[{"hashrate":50},{"hashrate":10},{"hashrate":35},{"hashrate":20}]';
$poolminers = json_decode($json, false);

usort($poolminers, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->hashrate <=> $b->hashrate;
});

foreach ($poolminers as $miners) {
    echo $miners->hashrate . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
10
20
35
50
```

If you would like to sort by descending order just swap $a and $b like this:

```php
usort($poolminers, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b->hashrate <=> $a->hashrate;
});
```

Comment: I took out the hard coded $json and put it back to the original decode of json_decode (since it's not constants) and this is what I got...
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: usort(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, stdClass given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ravenmine\Pool\miners.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ravenmine\Pool\miners.php(51): usort(Object(stdClass), Object(Closure)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ravenmine\Pool\miners.php on line 51

Comment: That's because usort needs an array as a first argument and you passing an object. You can either cast this object to associative array by using (array) $object or just use json_decode($data, true) to get an array.

Comment: I did figure out the "true" part eventually - I still couldn't really get it to work the way I wanted, but it stopped erroring. Marking as answer accepted, but I ended up going the really old fashioned way (a=b b=c c=a).